# Whats the use of creating a base theme and extending it to be used as your app theme

Tags: android, android-theme

When I create a new app in my Android studio the app theme is like -

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

However google tutorials ([like this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/material-design-style/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#2)) seems to create a base theme first and then create App theme extending it.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</item>
    <!-- Light Indigo -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#3949AB</item>
    <!-- Dark Indigo -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#00B0FF</item>
    <!-- Blue -->
</style>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"></style>
```

I am wondering is there a good usecase for such a design or is it just modularization?

If it does hold a good use case Studio should incorporate it as well?

PS : I am using latest studio build from dev channel.

Comment: the main reason is to remove redundancy. your app might be mixture of full screen activities, activities with tool bar, etc. but still similar appearance for popups or menus. thats why we write common properties in base theme and extend them to other themes for specific task.

Comment: you can relate it with java inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example if you want a certain theme to be the main theme of your app, you can set what you want to be the same for every activity, and then you can extend it and add for example different font size, button color, text color ecc, depending of want your activity needs. But the main theme is the same in any activity without any redundant code.

Hope this helps!